# CSS hex color bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

When you see a question in Code Review with some CSS and hex color codes in it, it appears like a comment.

I think the syntax highlighter thinks that CSS uses python style comments i.e. `print "2" #here is a comment`.

It should be a different color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The default syntax highlighter uses a "one size tries to fit all" approach, which will not always be successful. I have changed the setting for the [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) tag such that not the default highlighter, but the CSS-specific highlighter is used for questions with this tag ([example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12054/which-is-a-better-optmized-css-for-a-button-design)).

In general, you can also manually specify which highlighter is to be used, by inserting

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
```

right before the corresponding codeblock. See the [syntax highlighting section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in the editing help for details, and [this answer on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) for a list of supported highlighters.